# Kubernetes refuses to work with rkt, containers not starting, wrong systemd error

Tags: kubernetes, coreos, etcd, flannel, rkt

I have hit a wall trying to setup kubernetes with rkt on coreos when deploying the master node.

[**This**](http://pastebin.com/raw/thLd0r2R) is the main problem I see from the kubelet logs...some systemd error which is obviously wrong because coreos latest stable uses 225...

I have followed the [Deploy Kubernetes Master Node(s)](https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/deploy-master.html) and the [Running Kubernetes on rkt](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/rkt/) guides.

I have tried all the `hyperkube` images from `quay.io` and the rkt versions `1.0.0`,`1.2.1`, `1.5.1` making sure to switch the correct `fly` aci image in the [kubelet-wrapper](https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/kubelet-wrapper.html)...no changes whatsoever.

Comment: Please, provide us with the exact logs and/or error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for who missed the link to the log: http://pastebin.com/raw/thLd0r2R (it was the link on "this" which I bolded now)

Anyway seems like the kubelet is still not ready to run containerized, so I managed to bootstrap a setup with the kubelet ran from binary, still using rkt for `scheduler` `apiserver`and `controller`, and using a second wrapper for the `proxy` because the proxy needs `stage1-fly`.

So it is composed of:

- systemd unit for rkt-api `/usr/bin/rkt run apiserver ...`
- systemd unit for the proxy `/usr/bin/rkt run coreos/hyperkube proxy...--stage1-path=/usr/share/rkt/stage1-fly.aci ...`
- systemd unit for the kubelet `/opt/bin/kubelet ...`
- k8s manifests for apiserver, scheduler, controller

Sadly there is the bug that the hyperkube does not catch the kubectl flags so I also have to use the kubectl binary besides the kubelet binary and the containerized hyperkube bin. Eventually the hyperkube will be all that is needed with only 1 systemd unit and the manifests.